# Gmail one click unsubscribe 2024

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, unsubscribe

Saw that gmail [will require one click unsubscribe in 2024](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?sjid=10741995214756990434-NA), starting in February. But to me, it's unclear how this would need to be set up based on how they explain it below. Right now I have a 2 click way of unsubscribing via AMPscript/CloudPage, but instead of changing that it's suggesting adding something in the headers? Has anyone set this up and/or can help me understand what actually needs to be done from a marketing cloud perspective?

**From the link above**:

Make it easy to unsubscribe
Always give your recipients an easy way to unsubscribe from your messages. Letting people opt out of your messages can improve open rates, click-through rates, and sending efficiency. One-click unsubscribe makes it easy for people to opt out. If you send more than 5,000 message per day, your marketing and subscribed messages must support one-click unsubscribe.

To set up one-click unsubscribe, include both of these headers in outgoing messages:

List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
List-Unsubscribe: https://solarmora.com/unsubscribe/example
When a recipient unsubscribes using one-click, you receive this POST request:

"POST /unsubscribe/example HTTP/1.1
Host: solarmora.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 26
List-Unsubscribe=One-Click"

Learn more about List-Unsubscribe: headers in [RFC 2369](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2369) and [RFC 8058](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8058).

Edit:
If i'm seeing this unsubscribe button on gmail accounts that receive our emails, does that mean it's already enabled?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this article from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387977&type=1)? In terms of unsubscribe, it depends on whether you're talking about Marketing Cloud or the Salesforce platform. Salesforce (platform) can only send more than 5000 emails to external email addresses a day, whereas it can send many more to Users via their registered email addresses. I don't think the latter comes into scope for one click unsubscribe since the email address for the user is controlled by the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and sorry if I wasn't clear too, I'm only talking about Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marketing Cloud has been providing one click unsubscribe for several years, by using List-Unsubscribe header: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_one_click_header_unsubscribe.htm&type=5

It shows as a native *link* in your email client.

[image]

When you click that link, SFMC is notified about your intent to unsubscribe, and updates your subscriber status from Active to Unsubscribed.

Comment: Hi Lukas - im struggling to know what i need to implement in my email (i have no code resource available). Do you have some more guidance on how the code would look embedded in my email? And what i would need to set up in MC? I’m using a Cloud Page and buttons which update SalesCloud using a Journey.

Comment: @user48743 - not sure what you are referring to. The list-unsubscribe header does not require any steps from your side to set up. When someone clicks on the Unsubscribe button in the client (like the Gmail screenshot in your example), the status is updated to Unsubscribed in All Subscribers list. It is also creating an entry in _Subscribers data view, which you can query, and add the Subscribers to your existing journey which will unsubscribe them in Sales Cloud.

Comment: Thanks Lukas - i'm not seeing this when i open my emails is there anything stopping this from appearing? I'm using the commercial send classifications. this is where im not sure what i need to set up: 'To set up one-click unsubscribe, include both of these headers in outgoing messages:
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click List-Unsubscribe: https://solarmora.com/unsubscribe/example When a recipient unsubscribes using one-click, you receive this POST request:
"POST /unsubscribe/example HTTP/1.1 Host: solarmora.com Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length:'...

Comment: @user48743 - did you bother checking the email headers of emails going out from SFMC with Commercial send classification?

Comment: Thanks Lucas - I’m not sure what im looking for, though the default header is blank. I think someone has created a custom block at the top of the emails but i dont see any list or unsubscribe in it. If its automatically added but i dont see it.

Comment: @user48743 Depending on what email client you use, there are different ways of viewing headers. E.g. in Gmail, you should open the email and find the menu item called _Show original_ and search for list-unsibescribe there.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas! - do you know how I change the email address that the unsubscribe is going to? I currently dont know where this is sending or if this should even be sent to a company email address internally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150759/discussion-between-lukas-lunow-and-user48743).

Answer (score -1):

As per your edit comment and attached image, your one-click list-unsubscribe is working on your Gmail client.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/210104)

Comment: Hi Derek, 
This answer is in response to the Edit comment in the question. I didn't see any response added to that question. Hence I answered it.